# Nginx: $args $arg_param $query_string inside if statement

Tags: regex, configuration, nginx

I have difficulties to apply this if statement in my nginx config:

```
location / {
    break;
    proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:4444;
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host                        $host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    if ($arg_charset ~* windows-1251) {
        charset                     windows-1251;
    }
    source_charset              utf-8;
}
```

I have tried $arg_charset ~* "windows-1251" and $arg_charset ~* /.*windows-1251.*/ and all others solutions. None does work...
Removing if statements give me wanted results, so the problem is inside if statement condition.

It's a bug or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: if ( $arg_charset ) doesn't work as well. Changed to location ~* ^.*$ and it's not helping as well.

Comment: using url?charset=windows-1251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil explains, `if` blocks inside a `location` are known to be potentially problematic when they contain anything other then a `return` or `rewrite`

try simply moving the if into the `server` block directly (where `if` has no problems) that should fix it.

updated to avoid using `charset` directive in serverblock:

try something like the following:

```
set $requestedcharset utf-8;
if ($arg_charset ~* windows-1251) { set $requestedcharset windows-1251;}

location / {
  source_charset utf-8;
  charset $requestedcharset;
  #add in the rest of your / config
}
```

NOTE: make sure you have the win-utf `charset_map` included in your http block (on my debian system that means `include /etc/nginx/win-utf;`)

Comment: The problem is that charset directive is not allowed in server context... I guess i'll have to try urls insteal of GET parameters and build separate location block. Btw can i include GET parameters inside location statement?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset has `server` as allowed context for `charset`, so that should work

Comment: Yea but without if statement, what it not a solution for me. I'll try your solution you have updated.

Comment: It's working, but it doesn't return utf-8 back if there is no charset variable in the query or it's not windows-1251. Charset is always windows-1251...

Comment: Creating separate location blocks with different charset in them works. It's a pain in the ass...really... :D